# Advancing arrays in Apple swift 2.1

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Lets say I have an array...

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and I use the removeFirst function to remove the first value in the array.

```
array.removeFirst()
```

There is now an empty value at the first position in the array. How would I go about advancing the array so that the value from position two moves up to position one and so on. i.e. the array would now look like this

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Do I have to create my own function for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the `removeFirst()` method will take care of that for you. It's not possible for a Swift `Array` to ever contain an "empty position".

Comment: does the removeFirst() return nil if the array is empty?

Comment: No, it crashes. Use `popFirst()` to safely remove the first member, and return an optional.